# indices for more than one needle in Perl 6

Tags: search, raku

I want to find `indices` for more than one letter in a word. I don't want to use `Regex`es, because they will slow down the program (which is already slower than I wanted).

```perl6
> "banana".indices(("a", "b").any)
any((1 3 5), (0))
```

How can I instead get `0, 1, 3, 5`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would go for something like this (in the REPL):

```
> gather "banana".indices("a"|"b").deepmap: *.take
(1 3 5 0)
```

Answer (score 8):

```
> "banana".comb.grep: 'a' | 'b',:k
(0 1 3 5)
```

I don't know if `comb` use `regex` in this case:

```
gather for 'banana'.comb.antipairs  {.value.take if .key ∈ ['a','b'] } 

# or
gather 'banana'.comb.antipairs».&{.value.take if .key ∈ ['a','b'] }
```

Comment: Nice, but the OP said he didn't want to use regex.

Comment: @Håkon Hægland is `"banana".comb` equals to `"banana".comb(/./)`

Comment: Sorry I wasn't thinking.  Although the name `grep` comes from "global regexp" it  is not using regex here. `'a'  | 'b'` is just a junction of two characters. I am not sure about `comb`, but I see no reason why it should use regex.

Comment: Actuallly, `.comb` does *not* use any regexes internally.  It just creates an iterator on all graphemes in the string.

Answer (score 7):

My solution would be:

```
> <a b>.map( { |"banana".indices($_) } ).sort
(0 1 3 5)
```

Basically, loop over all of the letters you want to look for (`<a b>.map`) and map those letters to their indices (`"banana".indices($_)`), then slip the indices found (`|`) and sort the result (`.sort`).

Comment: Which version, do you think, will be the fastest?

Comment: @EugeneBarsky What is fastest today may not be the fastest in the future. It may also be dependent on your particular data. If speed is important to you, I recommend trying the different approaches on your machine with your data (or a representative sample of your data).

Comment: @ChristopherBottoms Thanks, I'll try it.